# Controller level permission

Tags: acl, phalcon

Consider following code:

```
$acl = new Phalcon\Acl\Adapter\Memory();

$acl->setDefaultAction(Phalcon\Acl::DENY);

//Register roles
$acl->addRole(new Phalcon\Acl\Role('guest'));
$acl->addRole(new Phalcon\Acl\Role('member', 'guest'));
$acl->addRole(new Phalcon\Acl\Role('admin', 'user'));

$acl->addResource(new Phalcon\Acl\Resource('user'));
$acl->addResource(new Phalcon\Acl\Resource('index'));

$acl->allow('member', 'user', array());
$acl->allow('guest', 'index', array());

$acl->isAllowed('guest','index','index'); //returns false
```

I want grant permission at controller level, I mean when write: 
    $acl->allow('member', 'user');
It grant member of actions of user controller, I do not want add all actions of user controller manually. How can I implement this idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a good example implementing Acl in the sample application called [INVO](https://github.com/phalcon/invo), the [Security](https://github.com/phalcon/invo/blob/master/app/plugins/Security.php) plugin implements an Acl list, the resources regarding the public areas use a '*' as a wildcard to add a rule for every action in the controller:

```
<?php

$publicResources = array(
    'index' => array('index'),
    'about' => array('index'),
    'session' => array('index', 'register', 'start', 'end'),
    'contact' => array('index', 'send')
);
foreach($publicResources as $resource => $actions){
    $acl->addResource(new Phalcon\Acl\Resource($resource), $actions);
}

//Grant access to public areas to both users and guests
foreach($roles as $role){
    foreach($publicResources as $resource => $actions){
        $acl->allow($role->getName(), $resource, '*');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, In documentation there is no info about `*` parameter, also it seems ye that it is required that every action be added by `addResources` function. It seem adding adding `*` is redundant and if third parameter omitted it implicitly means all actions are allowed/denied.  ZF followed this approach: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.permissions.acl.intro.html

Comment: How to grant all resources for a specific role? `*` does not work for resources.